# Covariant derivative depends only on a point?

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reviewing the definition of a covariant derivative and I saw that in my script they said, that for example: $\nabla^{\text{can}}_{x} Y(p)$ depends only on $Y$ in direction of $X(p)$. My question is now is it the case in general and how can I show this?

Many thanks for some help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be seen in coordinates around $p$, as $$(\nabla_XY)_p = \sum_{k=1}^n \left({\rm d}Y^k_p(X_p) +\sum_{i,j=1}^n \Gamma_{ij}^k(p)X^i(p)Y^j(p)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\bigg|_p.$$Note that this expression depends on $X$ only through $X_p$ and on $Y$ only through $Y_p$ and the coefficients ${\rm d}Y^k_p(X_p)$ -- the latter being determined if one knows the values of $Y$ along the integral curve of $X$ starting at $p$, near $p$.